# Wait until API request ends and store the res in var Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promise

I have a problem with my project.
I'm trying to set API request and once it done I want to store the res in var.

My code:

```
function getMyBtcBalace(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  bit2c.getBalance(credentials, function(error, balance)  {
     resolve(balance.BTC);
     //return
  })
 });
}

///After API call
var temp = getMyBtcBalace();
```

In my project I want to get the updatest value of balace.BTC every time I call getMyBtcBalace function.

As you can see I use Promise, but I don't want continue coding in then() function.

Example:

```
 function AsyncFunc(){
  ///// Async
  }

function getMyBtcBalace(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  bit2c.getBalance(credentials, function(error, balance)  {
     resolve(balance.BTC);
     //return
  })
 });
}

while (getMyBtcBalace() > AsyncFunc2())
{
  /// Do something 
}
```

Comment: Because I don't want to continue coding in then(), I just want to call getMyBtcBalace and to get an answer!

Comment: You can't continue coding outside the `.then()`.  That's how asynchronous operations work in Javascript.  The only place you can use the async result is INSIDE the `.then()` handler or in some function you call from there and pass it the result.  See the question yours has been marked a duplicate of for lots more explanation and coding options.

Comment: So want you're saying is that I can't work outsite the then() function, so how I can do the while loop.

Comment: Just to make things clear, I want to call 5 different API requests and use it.
So I can\t work in one then() function because I have 4 more to deal with

Comment: I just edited my Q , please see :-)